# How to override es-lint rules in a specific file, in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm using some "legacy" code in my React app. Webpack throws countless "no-restricted-globals" and "no-undef" errors, and doesn't allow me to compile.

I would like to override this functionality in the specific problematic file. If not possible, i'm willing to disable those es-lint features all together.

How can it be done? I'm using an app that wasn't booted with react-create-app

Comment: If anybody is interested, i just added lines to the specific file, of this nature: /* eslint no-undef: off */

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell ESLint to ignore specific files and directories by creating an .eslintignore file in your project’s root directory. The .eslintignore file is a plain text file where each line is a glob pattern indicating which paths should be omitted from linting. For example, the following will omit all JavaScript files:

**/*.js

https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories